# C# Emgu CV get name of capture

Tags: c#, video-capture, emgucv

I use the Emgu.CV.VideoCapture class to capture an external camera connected via usb.
However sometimes I have the problem that the capture seems to switch internally to my integrated laptop camera.

I want to re-check the selected camera in away like this:

```
capture = new VideoCapture(cameraIndex);

string cameraName = capture.GetCameraName();
```

the method `GetCameraName()` does not exist and the `capture.Get()` method does not provide a returning of the camera name.

Any workaround that would give me the camera name is also a solution for me.